# how can we add another left sidebar to our site

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

i m working on wordpress with bootstrap theme.i m using a Main left-sidebar on my site.as i put the code into WIDGETS> MainSidebar but now i have a problem that on clicking a link i want to open another page having same as my home page but different sidebar.how can i achieve it??

Here is my Template for bootstrap:Page Template (page.php)

```
<?php
/** page.php
 *
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @author      Konstantin Obenland
 * @package     The Bootstrap
 * @since       1.0.0 - 07.02.2012
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="span9">
    <?php tha_content_before(); ?>
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php tha_content_top();

        the_post();
        get_template_part( '/partials/content', 'page' );
        comments_template();

        tha_content_bottom(); ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
    <?php tha_content_after(); ?>
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();


/* End of file page.php */
/* Location: ./wp-content/themes/the-bootstrap/page.php */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have two different sidebars.
Put sidebar code in a custom template name them you like.

see how to Create custom template [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages)

and use wordpress conditional tags like.

```
if(is_page( 2 )){ // 2 is page id
get_template_part( 'custom', 'sidebar' ); //  (custom-sidebar.php)
}
else{ 
get_sidebar();
}
```

[conditionnal tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

By this way you can have 2 sidebars on different pages.

Comment: I HAVE TRIED BUT NOT SUCCEEED IN IT.can u tell me that as in my page.php template i have get_sidebar so now i can make another sidebar through it and then can use the conditional tags for it.but i m unable to found that from where this get_sidebar() function is coming??

Comment: u can create new sidebar , [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) and [second link](http://www.tastyplacement.com/add-sidebar-wordpress)

Comment: ok but as i mentioned in my above code that get_sidebar().i just want to know that wher is this function is defined.